# What is the difference between pywin32 and pypiwin32?

Tags: python, pywin32

I am trying to automate Microsoft Office applications and after some Googling, I came across pypiwin32 and pywin32 to interact with Windows Component Objects. My question is, what's the difference between the two libraries?

I have tried Googling but all the information I found seem to be outdated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Pypiwin32 is an old and outdated repackaging of pywin32 from its creator to use wheels. It is abandoned for a long time. You should just use pywin32.