# my pip module pywin32 not installing. its give me error. i tried so much tricks like reinstall pip and python but couldn't found my error

Tags: python, pywin32

i tried so many things like reinstalling, path setting
give this type of error while install pywin32.

**Collecting pypiwin32

Using cached pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)

Using cached pypiwin32-219.zip (4.8 MB)

Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1

╰─> [7 lines of output]

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 2, in 

File "", line 34, in 

File "C:\Users\3563tu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fn06ble2\pypiwin32_74a1c02ec5424c6293525e093c6dcd0b\setup.py", line 121
print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version

^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Building pywin32", pywin32_version)?

[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.

╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

hint: See above for details.

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages)

WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.9\site-packages)**\

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'.` is the issue. This means that this package is for python 2 and doesn't have a python 3 version. PyPI [info page](https://pypi.org/project/pypiwin32/#description) doesn't have any info at all on this package.

Comment: @Edoakse do you know how i solve it.as a beginer of this industry i dont know how to solve. it can you help me?.

Comment: First off, you should not start new projects in Python 2. It's [deprecated](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) for more than 2 years now. Unless you have an unavoidable need to use this particular module, don't use it. If you absolutely have to use this module, you should install python 2, and create a virtualenv (and actiavte it) and use that for your development. Google is your friend for this. Look up the following: `install python 2 in MY_OPERATING_SYSTEM`, `create virtualenv for python 2 in MY_OPERATING_SYSTEM`, `using virtualenv`. That should be enough to get you started...

Comment: @EdoAkse Faced same problem while installing below
"sudo pip install pypiwin32"
I have python 3.10.4 ver (no other python vers installed).
Error is related to setip.py file.
Part of error:
"python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
File "/tmp/pip-install-0qiyf_4f/pypiwin32_799cd82de851463d8ed0c834d6d0c0e1/setup.py", line 121
print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
"

Comment: so don't use sudo for pip. but that package is outdated. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55918399/9267296)